# Invalid character for ; using reader.NextResult

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

```
string sql = @"SELECT sum(subtotal) FROM table1 WHERE clientid=:v1;" +
"SELECT * FROM table2  WHERE clientid = :v2 "
cmd = DBConnection.GetCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add(":v1", "Name1");
cmd.Parameters.Add(":v2", "Name2");
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //Error: Invalid Character
while (reader.Read())
{
  ..results from first query
}
reader.NextResult();
while (reader.Read())
{
  ..results from second query
}
```

.NET is not allowing reader.NextResults using binding variables? Why i am getting Invalid Character??

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `:` when adding parameters to the command.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("v1", "Name1");
cmd.Parameters.Add("v2", "Name2");
```

[OracleCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When using named parameters in an SQL statement called by an
>   OracleCommand of CommandType.Text, you must precede the parameter name
>   with a colon (:). **However, in a stored procedure, or when referring
>   to a named parameter elsewhere in your code (for example, when adding
>   OracleParameter objects to the Parameters property), do not precede
>   the named parameter with a colon (:).** The .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle supplies the colon automatically.

Comment: Habib, you suggest that my query should look like: string sql = @"SELECT sum(subtotal) FROM table1 WHERE clientid=v1;" +
"SELECT * FROM table2  WHERE clientid =v2 "  ?

Comment: @user2369009, not the query text, it should be the command parameters. Refresh the page. You should **remove `:` while adding parameters**

Comment: It didn't solved my issue. The queries are returning valid results in oracle. I changed to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(v1, "Name1");

Comment: No. your parameter should be added like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("v1", "Name1");`

Comment: It looks that it was not about that. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("v1", "Name1");